# How did this generalized NJL model from 1993 predict Higgs boson and top quark masses?

Tags: renormalization, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

Since the Higgs boson was found in 2012, at a mass around 125 GeV, it has often been remarked that this is curiously close to ["criticality" or "metastability" or a false vacuum](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.6497), if one supposes that the standard model is correct up to very high energies. A Higgs mass of 126 GeV was in fact [predicted in 2009](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0208), by making exactly that assumption, along with a further assumption about physics at the quantum gravity scale ("asymptotic safety"). For that matter, there's [a paper from 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01107) also arguing that the mass of the top quark (first detected in 1995) could also have been predicted from the assumption of asymptotic safety. (The top quark mass also has a prominent role in determining these properties such as vacuum stability.)

At least since the 1980s, most particle theorists thought that there must be particles beyond the standard model, with masses around the electroweak scale, in order to solve the hierarchy problem; and that new particles would also allow an exact unification of coupling constants at grand unification energies, as well as explaining dark matter. For all these reasons, the idea that the standard model might be exactly true all the way up to grand unification or quantum gravity energy scales, was not given much consideration. It's still very much a minority position, but there are now a lot of people thinking about it, judging by the citations of the three papers mentioned above.

In this regard, I would like to draw attention to [a paper from 1993 by David and Sidney Kahana](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9312316). The authors also [revisited their model in 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.2794), on the eve of the Higgs discovery. Judging by their number of citations, these papers are all but unknown. But they did catch the attention of one person - Peter Higgs himself! See the very end of [this memoir by the experimental physicist Michael Tannenbaum](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06934), where Higgs acknowledges that the Kahanas correctly predicted the masses of the Higgs boson and the top quark in 1993.

So how did they do it? As in the case of asymptotic safety, they make a postulate about high-energy physics, and then extrapolate its implications down to lower energies. Specifically, they posit a kind of "NJL model", in which there are [four-fermion contact interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-fermion_interactions) at high energies, as in Fermi's model of the weak interaction, prior to the modern discovery of W and Z electroweak gauge bosons. In the Kahana model, the four-fermion interactions are among all the standard model fermions, and all the known gauge bosons emerge as bound states. (I will point out that [a similar generalized NJL model](https://inspirehep.net/literature/29694) was said to be equivalent to the standard model in 1991.)

Tentatively, I interpret the success of the Kahanas, not as a mere coincidence, but as a sign that particle physics really is nothing but standard model, at least up to scales of 10<sup>11</sup>-10<sup>14</sup> GeV (as mentioned in their 2011 paper); that the Higgs and top couplings assume small special values at those scales, for an unknown reason; and that this also explains the results derived much later, from the assumption of asymptotic safety. As I mentioned, this contradicts the usual approach to the hierarchy problem, but these days, a lot of people are [casting around for alternative approaches](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.05708) anyway. (See the end of part 5 for approaches that are cognizant of Higgs criticality.)

However, the NJL model (along with its relatives, like the Gross-Neveu model) is unfamiliar to me. I'm certainly not fluent in its technicalities. What I really want to know is,

**Is this a tenable interpretation of the success of the Kahana model?**

If we do suppose that physics is just "standard model", all the way to the GUT scale, with appropriate boundary conditions for the Higgs and top couplings - is that enough to explain  the predictive success of the Kahana model?